# Is it possible to bind docker ports to a dedicated ip address

Tags: docker, networking, docker-for-mac

Every time I bind docker ports using `docker -p 80:80` or using docker-compose

```
ports:
- "80:80"
```

It binds to localhost (aka. 127.0.0.1) making a conflict with other services running on local machine.

I know I could just bind to other ports than 80 but I prefer to use port 80 with `/etc/hosts`

Is there a way to create a dedicated IP that all docker containers will bind to instead of localhost (eg. 127.0.1.1) so I could use localhost for my local services and that other IP for docker services?

I am using docker-compose with docker-on-mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual interface and assign ip to the containers.

Link:

[Create Virtual Interface](http://programster.blogspot.com/2013/01/ubuntu-create-gatwayrouter-pc-with.html)

Comment: I ment more of, how to do it than what to do.
I managed to create an alias for my loopback interfacte with ip 10.4.0.1 and then I tried to use this config and set ip option to 10.4.0.1 but that did nothing.
https://forums.docker.com/t/can-i-change-the-default-ip-from-0-0-0-0-when-binding/30358/4